# combine jquery rules

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have this jquery

```
$('#1').fancybox({
'width': '50%',
'height': '90%',
'autoDimensions': false,
'type': 'ajax',
'ajax': {
    dataFilter: function(data) {
        return $(data).find('.news:first')[0];
    }
}
});
$('#2').fancybox({
'width': '50%',
'height': '90%',
'autoDimensions': false,
'type': 'ajax',
'ajax': {
    dataFilter: function(data) {
        return $(data).find('.news:eq(1)')[0];
    }
}
});
```

is there a possibility combine these 2 into 1

THNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem is the `dataFilter` but you could try something like this:

```
$('#1, #2').each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).fancybox({
    'width': '50%',
    'height': '90%',
    'autoDimensions': false,
    'type': 'ajax',
    'ajax': {
      dataFilter: function(data) {
        return $(data).find('.news:eq(' + i + ')')[0];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Like this?**

```
$('#1, #2').fancybox({
    'width': '50%',
    'height': '90%',
    'autoDimensions': false,
    'type': 'ajax',
    'ajax': {
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            return $(data).find('.news:eq(1)')[0];
        }
    }
});
```

You can combine selectors as you do in CSS by separating them with commas.

**Edit:**
`:first` is just a shorthand for `:eq(0)`, so the only differance between your settings were the selectors. Quote from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/):

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent
>   to :eq(0).

Comment: yes i Know but look a the the ajax datafilter is getting something from a div and showing it on opening div 1 ore 2 in fancybox